# RESTEasy serialization of Object does not include nested objects

Tags: jakarta-ee, jackson, resteasy

I have a REST service that sends an Object A. This object contains the reference to another Object of type B. When I request the Object A through the REST service, I obtain all the fields of A but the field containing B.

I would like to have a Json including the nested objects of the class.

The fields that are not serialized have this tags:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST})
private B b;

@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade={CascadeType.ALL},orphanRemoval=true)
private C c;
```

I also tried changin LAZY by EAGER but no luck.

Comment: Do you have a public getter in A on B? By default Jackson does not serialize private field

Comment: Yes, I do have getter and setters for all fields, just that the two affected fields have different function names than the rest. Instead of getB() setB(B b) I have b() and b(B b). (The class is generated by a third party) Do you think that could be the problem?

Comment: Absolutely. All those frameworks using reflection are based on the java beans standard which dictates to have getter and setter. The other possibility is to configure jackson to access your private field for serialization.

Comment: I am really interested in that solution because I cannot modify the class, and because I also need to modify the deserialization configuration. Could you explain that in an answer and I select it as the correct one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Jackson does not serialize private fields. If you want to change this behavior you could annotate your class with the following:

```
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.ANY, getterVisibility = Visibility.NONE, setterVisibility = Visibility.NONE)
public class A{...
```

Comment: I just have to solve the fact that when deploying, it does not find the jackson module of annotations but looks the correct way to go. I also tested temporary the replacement of private to public qualifier to verify that it serialize the field in that case; it does.

Comment: you could alternatively use @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) instead of @JSonAutoDetect. You won't have any module/class not found in that case.